# How to display commit number on asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, git

I am very beginner in asp.net.
Is there an easy way to see number of published commit (hash) on website. I have several versions of website published and I'd like to see on which commit particular published version is working.

Is there any easy way similar to [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")] but displaying commit SHA instead of version number?

Comment: You would need to have a step in your CI process (before build) to get the commit hash from git and inject it into the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

Comment: Assuming you have a pre-compiled web project: https://github.com/Fody/Stamp (currently without a maintainer; injects the current git info into the IL as part of the build process); https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion alternative, recommended by Fody Stamp creator.